# How did Alan lose his chiropractic license?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, two-and-a-half-men

In season 12, episode *Here I come, pants*:

> Walden: "We'll gonna lose everything we worked for over one stupid mistake."
>
> Alan: "It's my chiropractic license all over again."

I can't remember a recent episode, in which Alan's work was mentioned or a situation that led to the loss of his chiropractic license.

Was there anything mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in season 11, episode 1:

> *Walden:* I hired you to be my assistant to help you out financially because you had to close your chiropractical...
>   *Alan:* I did not have to close it, I'm in a rent dispute.
>   *Walden:* People in rent disputes don't fake their own deaths!

Answer (score 1):

In S12E10, Alan says the following:

> It's my chiropractic license all over again.
>   **Your hand slips into one butt crack.**
>
> Source: [transcript S12E10 by springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=two-and-a-half-men&episode=s12e10).

Based on that, it seems Alan touched at least one of his clients inappropriately, triggering a board review causing him to lose his license (this is established in S11E03, see quote below):

> But I can help you.
>   Although I am legally obligated to tell you my license has expired.
>   But thankfully backs haven't changed that much **since my unsuccessful board review.**
>
> Source: [transcript S11E03 by springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=two-and-a-half-men&episode=s11e03).